# Can't install chromecast companionlibrary

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm building a library for react native by using the chromecast companionlibrary.

When I add `compile 'com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary:ccl:2.8.4'`, gradle sync fails with:

> Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary:ccl:2.8.4

Weird thing is that i have other project that is not a library, and i don't receive any error messages.

Any idea?

Comment: Is jCenter in your listed repos?

Comment: yeah @AliNaddaf, jcenter() and mavenCentral()

Comment: @AliNaddaf im adding the dependency in my build.gradle. as this is a library, im adding apply plugin: 'com.android.library' instruction.

my other project is a normal one, and it works ok when i add the companionlibrary.

just the library that has as a dependency the companion library is the one that fails. not sure if the companion l. can't be used inside other libraries.

Comment: @AliNaddaf my bad, you were right. i confused the  buildscript repo with my project repo. is working great now :)